# AsyncTask seems to be freezing for multiple simultaneous requests

Tags: android-asynctask

I'm facing a situation here, when sending sequence of messages over TCP  socket using AsyncTask, except 2 out of 5 requests, none of the other  messages are sent over the network. I did packet capture using Wireshark as well but no success.

Here is the code (all these methods are in Service class). doTask() is the * method for sending messages over tcp socket using AsyncTasks. I even used ThreadPool but no success.

```
private class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<EASMessageBase, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(EASMessageBase... easMessageBases) {
            EASMessageBase msg = easMessageBases[0];
            try {
                //send data over tcp socket output stream
                tcpsocketOutputStream.sendPreparedMessage(msg);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

//DIDN'T WORK EXCEPT FIRST 2 REQUESTS
//without wait statement
public void doTask() {
    new SendMessage().execute(message1);
    new SendMessage().execute(message2);
    new SendMessage().execute(message3);
    new SendMessage().execute(message4);
    new SendMessage().execute(message5);
}

//WORKED
//using wait statement
public void doTask() {
    new SendMessage().execute(message1);
    sleep();
    new SendMessage().execute(message2);
    sleep();
    new SendMessage().execute(message3);
    sleep();
    new SendMessage().execute(message4);
    sleep();
    new SendMessage().execute(message5);
}

private void sleep() {
    try { 
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(500);
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
}

//DIDN'T WORK EXCEPT FOR FIRST 2 REQUESTS
//using handlers without timeout
public void doTask() {
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
//message 1
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new SendMessage().execute(message1);
    }
});

//message 2
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new SendMessage().execute(message2);
    }
});

//message 3
//message 4
//message 5
}


//THIS METHOD WORKED
/*using handlers with timeout (used same timeout, and incremental timeout for each message as well)
1. used same timeout for all messages (e.g. 200)
2. used incremental timeouts for all messages (e.g. 200 for message1, 300 for message2, etc)
*/
public void doTask() {
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

//message1
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new SendMessage().execute(message1);
        }
    }, 200);

//message2
//message3
//message4
//message5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your "not working example" you create 5 different AsyncTask's, each sending one message on the tcpsocketOutputStream. Each of these task perform asynchronosly,  more or less at the same time (depending how much CPU cores are available). I assume the tcpsocketOutputStream is not suitable to issue a sendPreparedMessage(msg) if it has not yet finished sending the former one.

How about to create only one AsyncTask and supply all 5 message in one call?

```
new SendMessage().execute(message1,message2,message3,message4,message5);
```

And in the doInBackground method you send the received 5 messages within a loop.

```
for (EASMessageBase msg : easMessageBases)
{
    // send the msg
}
```

Or each of your async task must open a socket connection for its own.

Comment: Thank you Heri for the response but the problem still persists. I even tried with the Emulator but same problem. I'm using Thread.sleep inside AsyncTask if there is more than one input variable. Is it the correct way?

Comment: Do you say it does not work if you execute more than one EASMessageBase's within the same SendMessage().execute without a sleep() between the single sendPreparedMessage calls, and it works with the sleep()?

Comment: Out of 5 messages only 2 are transmitted and yes, it works with sleep.

Comment: A sleep() is never a good idea (BTW: what does your sleep() method really do? The Thread.sleep() needs a long param). Another guess: is the tcpsocketOutputStream.sendPreparedMessage itself something asynchronous?

Comment: public void sendPreparedMessage(EASMessageBase msgbMessageObject)
            throws IOException {
        try {
            byte[] byt = getBytesFromObj(msgbMessageObject);
            tcpSocketOutputStream.write(byt, 0, iLen);
            tcpSocketOutputStream.flush();
        }
        catch (Exception te) {
            throw new IOException("Unable to send message to buyer in defined time.", te);
        }
    }

Comment: OutputStream tcpSocketOutputStream = tcpSocket.getOutputStream();